# How do you connect a POST to a different razor page loaded via AJAX into a modal popup?

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Edit: Have marked up where the error in the original code was stopping this from working.

I can find plenty of info and examples of this on MVC, but doesn't seem to apply for Razor Pages?

Simple scenario: I have a page (FooList) showing a list of Foo items. Each has an Edit button. This opens a modal popup with the layout (and data) coming from a second page (FooEdit).

The Edit form appears and populates fine, but I can't work out how to get it to post the data back to the FooEdit code behind?

List page, FooList.cshtml

```
@page
@model Pages.FooListModel

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FooListVM)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a onclick="openModal(@item.ID);">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Foo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form>   <---- Edit: ** This shouldn't be here **
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </form>   <---- Edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function openModal(i) {
        $.get("FooEdit?id="+i,
            null,
            data => {
                $("#editModal").modal("show");
                $("#editModal .modal-body").html(data);
            });
    };
</script>
```

Code behind, FooList.cshtml.cs

```
public class FooListModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<FooListVM> FooListVM { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        FooListVM = new List<FooListVM>
        {
            new FooListVM { ID = 1, Name = "Foo 1" },
            new FooListVM { ID = 2, Name = "Foo2" }
        };
    }
}

public class FooListVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Second page for the popup, FooEdit.cshtml

```
@page
@model Pages.FooEditModel

@(Layout=null)

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Name" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Stuff1" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Stuff2" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

And the code behind for the popup, FooEdit.cshtml.cs

```
public class FooEditModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public FooEditVM FooEditVM { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        FooEditVM = new FooEditVM
        {
            Name = $"This is item {id}",
            Stuff1 = "Stuff1",
            Stuff2 = "Stuff2"
        };
    }

    public void OnPost(int id)
    {
        // How do we get to here???
        var a = FooEditVM.Name;
    }
}

public class FooEditVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Stuff1 { get; set; }
    public string Stuff2 { get; set; }
}
```

I've been through all the MS Tutorial stuff on Asp.net Core 2.2, but it doesn't seem to cover this.

Also as a side question, although it works, is there a "ASP helper tag" way of doing the ajax bit?

Answer (score 1):

Have realised the problem was the 'form' tag in the Modal Dialog markup that was clashing the 'form' tag from the partial page. Removing it fixed everything using:

In FooEdit.cshtml

```
<form id="editForm" asp-page="FooEdit">
. . . 
</form>
```

In FooEdit.cshtml.cs

```
public void OnPost()
{
    // Fires in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the fooedit page is going to need some jQuery to handle this.

See below for what I would do in the fooedit page.

```
@page
@model Pages.FooEditModel

@(Layout=null)

  <form id=fooedit method="post" action="FooEdit">  
      <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Name" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Stuff1" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input asp-for="FooEditVM.Stuff2" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>    
  </form>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/Javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
    $("#fooedit").submit(function(e) {       
    e.preventDefault();        
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();
    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
          $("#editModal.modal-body").html(returnhtml);                  
        }           
    });    
    });    
});
</SCRIPT>
```